# Write from a worksheet to another using a macro added programmatically

Tags: vba, excel

I actually create worksheets programmatically and add button with a macro associated to these worksheets programmatically. What I want to do is that when I click on the button the content of the worksheet containing the button is copied to another worksheet.

There are actually two things that confuse me : **Firstly** I don't understand if the macro I associate to the button is located (I mean its code is located) in the file creating the worksheet or in the created worksheet itself.

Here is the code I create to add a button with an associated macro :

```
 With newWorkBook.Worksheets(1).Buttons
        .Add 350, 75, 173.25, 41.25
        .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "'!export_Click"
        .Caption = "Exporter la fiche"
      End With

      newWorkBook.Worksheets("Feuil1").Name = "Valeurs"
```

The `checkPVC_Click` Sub is in a module located in the Excel file used to generate the worksheets.

**Secondly**, within the macro that is supposed to copy the content of a worksheet to another, I don't know how to refer differently to the two worksheets (source and target) in the code.

In the code below :

```
Dim newWorkBook As Workbook
Dim createdSheetColumnsTab(100) As String
Dim col As Integer
col = Cells(1, 8).Value

Set newWorkBook1 = Workbooks.Add

newWorkBook1.Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Stat"

newWorkBook1.Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(2, 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Valeurs").Cells(12, 1)
```

Here in the line `col = Cells(1, 8).Value` I access to the content of the worksheet which content I want to copy, and in the line `newWorkBook1.Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Stat"` I access to the content of the "target" worksheet and I don't know how to refer to the content of the first worksheet in the following of the code in order to copy the content.

I hope I was clear, and I can add more precisions if necessary, sorry I don't master English so it's hard for me to explain the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave the `Sub checkPVC_Click` in the original workbook. Just ensure that you give full path and name of the file which has that macro. For example. Please ensure that the file from where you are running this macro is saved at least once.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim NewWorkbook As Workbook

    Set NewWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

    With NewWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Buttons
        .Add 350, 15, 173.25, 41.25
        .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "'!checkPVC_Click"
    End With
End Sub

Sub checkPVC_Click()
    MsgBox "a"
End Sub
```

Regarding your Second question, you need to fully qualify the `Cells` object so that it know which cells are you referring to

`ThisWorkbook` will refer to the cell from the workbook which hosts the code.

`Activeworkbook` will refer to the cell from the workbook which is currently active.

**Edit**: Followup from comments. Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim newWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set newWorkBook = Workbooks.Add
    Set ws = newWorkBook.Sheets(1)
    ws.Name = "Valeurs"

    With ws.Buttons
        .Add 350, 15, 173.25, 41.25
        .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "'!checkPVC_Click"
    End With
End Sub

Sub checkPVC_Click()
    Dim OldWorkbook As Workbook, newWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim createdSheetColumnsTab(100) As String

    Set OldWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

    Set newWorkBook1 = Workbooks.Add

    newWorkBook1.Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Stat"

    newWorkBook1.Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(2, 1) = OldWorkbook.Worksheets("Valeurs").Cells(12, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I use a first workbook to create a second workbook with a macro associated to a button. And I what that when I click on this button, the content of the second workbook is copied to a third workbook that is created, I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Yes you have to still use what I gave above. In `Sub checkPVC_Click()`, use `Activeworkbook` to copy from 2nd to 3rd.

Comment: I now get a runtime error : Subscript out of range (Error 9)

Comment: Can you update the question with the code that you are now using?

Comment: Are you creating that sheet in the 2nd workbook? Because all I can see is that you are adding a button to the new workbook. I do not see you creating any sheet with that name in the new file (2nd workbook)

Comment: I just change the name of the first sheet of the 2nd workbook to "Valeurs" : newWorkBook.Worksheets("Feuil1").Name = "Valeurs"``, this code is in the first workbook

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78321/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-otus).

Comment: Ok, I can't now actually because the filter of my company's computer doesn't allow me to access chat

Comment: @SiddharthRout I tested the code of your last edit and it works now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To access the content of the first worksheet of workbook containing macro you need to use:

```
Thisworkbook.sheets(1).range("a1:a100") ' range as an example you can input anything
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: did you try: thisworkbook.sheets(1).cells(1,8).copy destination:= newWorkBook1.Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(1, 8)

Comment: Yes, actually the copy works but the content copied is not from my "source" worksheet

Comment: So the source data is in the same wbk as code but a different specific sheet?

Comment: I use a workbook with a macro to programmatically create a new workbook containing a button with an associated macro, when I click on this button, I want the content of this workbook to be copied into an other workbook that is created.